# How to create tool tip for Android using Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8, delphi-10-seattle

I am developing android application using Delphi XE8. And I have doubt that how can I add the tool tip for Android application using Delphi.
Normally, the tool tip will be shown only at the first time of running the application. Also, how can I implement the same functionallity

Below link I have mentioned the tool tip for android using Java:[Tool Tip using JAVA](http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-tour-guide-tooltips-in-android-apps/33130)

Please suggest me that how can I implement using Delphi xe8

Comment: I think you should implement it by yourself instead of searching for libraries on `Firemonkey`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to add a hint or tooltip with FireMonkey?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417565/is-there-any-way-to-add-a-hint-or-tooltip-with-firemonkey)

Answer (score -1):

There is component called FMX toast Component you can download it from

[Here](https://www.cybertribe.de/info/components/fmx/toast/)

Usage is very easy and do the same approach you need .

also you can see how to do it using Android Helper.

[From Here](http://www.fmxexpress.com/pop-up-toast-like-info-messages-with-delphi-xe5-firemonkey-on-android-and-ios/)

Also check this answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417565/is-there-any-way-to-add-a-hint-or-tooltip-with-firemonkey)